# MySQL Connection lost after successfull query

Tags: mysql, transactions, connection

This question is theoretical. I've no real use case; I'm just trying to understand the MySQL behaviour.

Suppose I send a query (or a transaction) to the server (using transactional tables of course), and the query or transaction executes fine, but the connection is lost before the client (f.e., `mysql` or an App connecting to a remote server throught a C interface or any other framework like QtSQL) receives the answer of the server. So, the server knows the transaction finished properly, but the client doesn't because the answer didn't arrive.

What does it happen in this case? Does the server roll back the transaction even knowing that it finished succesfully? Any option to control the behaviour in these scenaries?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/packet-OK_Packet.html

Comment: The packet that is sent back is only done after the command has finished. In your case the command has completed and therefore has been COMMITTED in the logs...There would be no rolling back...

Comment: I wouldnt be worried about such a scenario since the response time between the completion of the query to the sending of the OK PACKET, is milliseconds, especially, if you had been able to maintain your connection to the server throughout the entire completion of the query.

Comment: I have never run across such a case, however this was interesting to think about and made me look a little deeper...+1

Comment: If you would want to see this in action more you can always write a script that executes every millisecond  `show processlist;` and `show engine innodb status;` to a file...That way you can analyze what is going on behind the scenes of the transaction engine and the threads as the query is executed and finished...